# How to track views on an item a la YouTube?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

I would like to be able to track views of an item in a way that I can see what items were the most viewed yesterday, last week or any given period.
How can I do that using either PHP or Rails? Is there a plugin for this in Rails, or is there a simple way of doing this using PHP/memcached?

Answer (score 2):

As Rémy says, you can make this simple and have a database table tracking individual page views, although this can incur a bit of write load on views, which might be undesirable.

A compromise could be to write a row for each view to an intermediate, in-memory table, and periodically (perhaps via a cron job, or every N views) update the aggregate count in the main table. If your read load is really high, then you *could* consider storing that temporary counter in memcached; as you'll spot, the less often you write to the disk-backed tables, the less fault tolerant your counter becomes, although in the case of a simple popularity counter, that's probably not critical data.

Once you've got your page view count, you can do whatever statistical analysis you fancy.

Comment: So is there something out there to help me out with the statistical analysis part?

Comment: +1. If you ever want to handle serious traffic (like a front-page digg), a database write as part of every page view is going to be unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a simple SQL table with the video id, the date and an integer counter, incremented for each view.

To filter multiple views from an IP address, use a table containing video id and ip address.
Truncate it each 24 hours, and increment the counter only if the ip address is not already in this table.

Answer (score 0):

For each view, save some data into a SQL table.

- Unique ID
- The item ID
- Date (unixtime for example)
- User's IP

Then you can COUNT(id) WHERE id = number AND date > last week

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM view_table WHERE id = 1 AND date > 1241136000
```